# How can choose the file from the dialog panel by using apple script?

Tags: applescript

How can choose the file from the dialog panel by using apple script?

When I write the script to activate the application, then it need to choose the file to open from the pop up dialog panel.

So, how to write of this script?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you mean something like this:

```
set theFile to choose file

tell application "" --enter the application you want to activate and open your file here
    activate
    open theFile
end tell
```